# I want to generate DDL for entire schema in oracle 10 G?

Tags: oracle

I am using Oracle 10G.

I am new to oracle, I have little bit regarding dbms_metadata.get_ddl, now using this utility i want to generate a DDL for my entire schema.

I mean what ever DDL operations done on my schema (testschema).

Please help me out.

Thanks

Nash.

Answer (score 4):

[SQL Developer -> Tools -> Database Export...](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17781_01/server.112/e18804/impexp.htm)

Answer (score 1):

Suggest you look into EXPDP. That can produce a full export of all the objects (with or without data) in a schema.

If it is a fairly 'plain' schema (no exotic objects and dependencies), you could script something based on

```
SELECT DBMS_METADATA.GET_DDL(object_type, object_name) FROM user_objects
```

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at my command-line tool [oraddlscript](http://devio.wordpress.com/category/oraddlscript/), which calls the GET_DLL() function for every object of a given user. The result can be written to one file per each object.

Comment: Hi Devio,

I am getting

D:\IhubTest\orascript\tool>oraddlscript.exe -s HYDIHUB
Error: The type initializer for 'Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleConnection' thre
w an exception.
Error: The provider is not compatible with the version of Oracle client

when i use oraddlscript. Please suggest me

Regards
Nash

Comment: @gnash-85 did you install ODAC? http://devio.wordpress.com/2009/11/04/oraddlscript-solving-odp-net-version-conflicts/ ODAC11 claims compatibility with all Oracle databases >= 9.2

Answer (score 0):

A really simple way is to create a new blank schema, compare your existing schema (testschema) against this using [Schema Compare for Oracle](http://www.red-gate.com/products/oracle-development/schema-compare-for-oracle/), and click on the Deployment button to generate the DDL automatically.